# Equivalent to Run Method(VBA) in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: vba, openoffice-calc

I have been trying to convert a VBA for Excel code to OpenOffice Calc (basic) and now Im having trouble accessing an external program (and it´s database) to generate an output which I will use later in my code. In other words, I give an input, call the program and later I want an output file.

In VBA:

```
Prog = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(2, 2) & IPRODB & " -i " & DateiAll_in 
Wait = True
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
RetVal = sh.Run(Prog, 0, Wait)
```

`Worksheets("Settings").Cells(2, 2)` is the program's path and `IPRODB` is the database's path, "-i" seems to be a command to the program and `DateiAll_in` is the Input file (`.csv`) I created before in the code.

The OpenOffice basic offers the function `Shell(Pathname, Windowstyle, Param, bSync)` to open external programs but It would not be the same since in the "run method" in VBA I am running a macro containing the program, its´s Database and Input File. (`expression.Run(MacroName, varg1,varg2, (...)`)

Is there any alternative to the Shell function or can I use it in the same way as I used the "run method" in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Shell function. In the first argument of the function I added all the equivalents of "Worksheets("Settings").Cells(2, 2) & IPRODB & " -i " & DateiAll_in". I substituted Worksheets("Settings").Cells(2, 2)  for the direct path of the program only because it was easier. So it worked with this code below:

```
Shell("C:\Program Files\*******\*****\*****.exe & IPRODB & "-i" & DateiAll_in",1,,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenOffice.org forums](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=7918) (didn't test it myself):

```
Dim oSvc as object
oSvc = createUnoService("com.sun.star.system.SystemShellExecute")

Rem Launch notepad
oSvc.execute(ConvertToUrl("C:\windows\notepad.exe"), "", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually used the Shell function and it worked fine at last.

Comment: OK - you may add a answer yourself, so other users get an overoview over the different solutions. You may even "accept" your own answer.